# how to retrieve messages from rabbitmq queues of a spring application

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I am able to send messages to the queue. Now I want those messages to be retrieved from queue and as the messages are `mailMessages` I want them to be sent to the users using data in the `mailMessages`. I am implementing the class MessageListener still I am not able to retrieve messages from queue.

[image: The image showing messages published into the queue]

Comment: There is a worked example here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Comment: I had seen that page earlier but i had been getting issues with creating beans, so i am trying to do it with the help of xml files. I am using rabbitmqlistenercontext.xml

Comment: I am implementing MessageListener for the class but still message listener is not working

Comment: Is there anyone to solve this issue, thanks in advance